# Add Hyperlink and Alt Text to Shape within With Statement

Tags: excel, vba

Got the following code to dynamically create connectors in my excel document based on range values however would like to add a hyperlink to each shape with alttext, can this be done from within the `With` statement.

```
With ws.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorStraight, Range(Rng(i, 1)).Left, _
    Range(Rng(i, 1)).Top, _
    Range(Rng(i, 2)).Left, _
    Range(Rng(i, 2)).Top)

    If parameters(i, 1) = "1" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    ElseIf parameters(i, 1) = "2" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf parameters(i, 1) = "3" Then
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End If

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

AlternativeText and Hyperlink are both properties of the shape object, so you wouldn't be able to do it within this particular `with` block. But you could do a `ForEach shape in ws.shapes` loop that defines those properties.

Comment: What order will VBA/Excel use when cycling through the shapes then? 

Will it be in order created?

Comment: Probably in order of index--each shape will have an index like shape(1), shape(2), etc. And .connector is a property with true/false. So `if shape.connector then shape.alternativetext="Hey I'm a connector" else debug.print "Don't worry about it."`

Comment: Another question sorry, if .AlternativeText is a property of Shape why can it not be called in the with block like I am calling the line in the with block to change line colour

Comment: The `with` command tells the compiler that it should only look at objects, methods, and properties in the division you specify, in this case `worksheet.shapes.addConnector`.